# Splitting spreadsheet strings into array values

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to split a value from a cell into separate array values. I am taking a list of emails from my spreadsheet and need to use the `addCommenters()` method.

Spreadsheets cell value: `email1@email.com, email2@email.com, email3@email.com` ... etc.

I need to split around the `", "` properly to pass the array into `addCommenters()`.

What is the programmatic way to do this?

Comment: The "duplicate" covers more than just splitting the string, I know.

Answer (score 4):

If you get the value of that cell (using .getValue())

```
var emails = sheet.getRange(range_here).getValue()
```

and then apply the [split()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) method

```
var commentersArray = emails.split(",")
```

you will have an array you can pass to the .addCommenters() method.

```
file.addCommenters(commentersArray);
```

Comment: I wasn't sure if this would work because it doesn't show the drop-down menu for this method. Why does it not autocomplete like other methods?

Comment: Not sure. Maybe because it is not a 'pure' GAS method but rather a javaScript method ?

Comment: That makes sense, it would be impractical to add all javascript in there. Can you please assist on my other question related to this same project?