# How to run function to split cell data when row added from jotform to google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Firstly thanks for taking the time to look at this, I'm a basic spreadsheet user and what I'd like to achieve here is way over my capability.

I'm using a jotform that collects data on bird sightings (user name, date, species, geolocation), a widget in the form grabs the phone location Latitude & Longitude and concatenates it into one cell (geolocation) with a comma separator eg(56.58542, -5.34016).

When the form is submitted it adds a new row to a google sheet, the sheet has 4x columns [user name] [date] [species] [geolocation].

When a new row is added by the form I'd like to automatically add two extra cells in that row [Latitude] [Longitude] that contain the Lat & Long split into them eg[56.58542] [-5.34016]. I can manually do this with the =SPLIT() function but I'd like to do this automatically as the row is added.

Is this possible and can someone either point me to where I can learn how to do this or post the information here?

Comment: Welcome. `=SPLIT` is, as you point out, a Google Sheets function, but `split` is also a Javascript [method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split). So you can use `split` in your script; google StackOverflow, there are many examples - this answer [Splitting spreadsheet strings into array values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33296552/1330560) provides the basics that you can adapt to your own scenario.

Comment: You'll also want to research [Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers), and specifically `onFormSubmit` which is an Installable Trigger [ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit) that will execute when a form submission is received by the spreadsheet.

Comment: How do you want to achieve this, via FUNCTION or via Script?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible with an ARRAYFORMULA() written in row 1.  it would look something like this.   Lets say the columns you're looking to populate are L and M. And that your Lat Long is currently in column K.  in cell L1, you would write just this one formula.  No headers above it, JUST this.

=ARRAYFORMULA({"Lat","Long";IF(K2:K="",,SPLIT(K2:K,", ",0))})

Hope that helps.